# Difference in count for PermissionSetAssignMent when GROUP BY either Id or Name

Tags: apex, soql, developer-console

I have following two queries

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), PermissionSetId 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(PermissionSetId) 
ORDER BY PermissionSetId LIMIT 1
```

And

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), PermissionSet.Name 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(PermissionSet.Name) 
ORDER BY PermissionSet.Name LIMIT 1
```

And these are the results in my dev org -

**Result #1**
[image]

**Result #2**
[image]

The only difference in these queries is that 1st is grouped by PermissionSetId and 2nd is by PermissionSet.Name

The issue is self explanatory - **Difference in count.**

Confirming that all permissionset names are unique.
I have spotted the permission set that is causing this, is there something fishy going on that permission?

Also confirming that i **don't** see this anomaly on all the orgs that i have tested.
All the permission set names are also unique

Comment: why are you using `LIMIT 1` for a Group by Rollup?

Comment: I did not wanted to show my entire result set for a concise screenshot.
You can try without the LIMIT

Comment: you say you spotted the permission set causing this, what is it? Is it a standard one or a custom one? fwiw, I don't see any difference in my org when running the same queries.